# Is it possible to work with an editor remotly?

Tags: ssh, server, editor

I want to edit files on my server, but don't want to always upload the files, is there a way on to edit the files remotly?

I tryed to make an bash script which should upload the files, but its not realy good :/ and sometimes didn't worked

Comment: There are many ways to do this, depending on which OS and editor you're using, or are willing to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Atom with the

[Retome FTP edit](https://atom.io/packages/ftp-remote-edit)

Package

Answer (score 0):

If you have got an SSH (SFTP enabled) access to your server, an option would be use use [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) to mount a remote directory on your local working path.

In this way you can use any editor (or even something else) to change your files and they will always be synchronised.

**Just keep in mind** that, in this way, files are actually located on your server, you won't have a real copy on your local machine.